# How to Convert from MemoryStream to FileStream to pass to MS Graph?

Tags: c#

I have a MemoryStream object that contains the contents of a file.  I would like to convert it from a MemoryStream to a FileStream in order to pass it to MS Graph's [LargeFileUploadTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.largefileuploadtask-1.-ctor?view=graph-core-dotnet)() method.

It seems that the method accepts the generic type called "Stream" so I tried using it as is, but it's taking a very long time.  In fact I get an HTTP timeout for larger streams.

I have another method similar to this one that also uses the LargeFileUploadTask and trying to upload the same file works - it's using a FileStream (the difference between the two methods is that one writes to a local file, and then opens a filestream before sending to MS Graph, and the one here receives a memorystream as a parameter)

**Code**

```
  private static async Task<Boolean> UploadInChunksToSharepoint(MemoryStream fileContents, string fileName)

 ....

 // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
 int maxSliceSize = 320 * 204800 * 4;
 var fileUploadTask =
 new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileContents, maxSliceSize);
```

**What I've Tried**

In reading other posts, I see that there's a WriteTo method in the fileContents object.  So i tried something like this:

```
 FileStream fileStream = new FileStream();
 fileContents.WriteTo(fileStream);
```

But ... I guess I can't do that because the FileStream doesn't allow you to just initialize without any parameters.  If there's a way... I'd like to be able to try this to compare apples to apples between the two methods to see why there's such a time diff.

In the meantime, I'm poking around the rest of the code to see if there might be other deltas that I just missed.

Comment: How big is the `MemoryStream` you're working with? Also, did you _rewind_ it first? (Forgetting to rewind a `MemoryStream` is a common gotcha)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a `FileStream` needs to be attached to an actual file. Your best bet if you *need* to use a FileStream is to probaby save the contents to a file and call `File.Open()` with the path as a parameter to get a stream.

Comment: @Dai, that's all it was.  I reset position to 0.  if you want to add as answer... i'll accept

Comment: *generic type called "Stream"* - advise to use the term "base" rather than "generic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP said the problem was that they forgot to *rewind* the `MemoryStream` before attempting to use it as the source of a HTTP request payload.

> @Dai, that's all it was. I reset position to 0. if you want to add as answer... i'll accept

Gladly.

---

So watch out if you have this:

```
using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() )
{
    using( StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter( ms, false ) )
    {
        CopyLoremIpsum( wtr );
    }
    
    await UploadStreamAsync( ms );
}
```

The `StreamWriter` (or any other writing action) will set the `MemoryStream.Position` to the *end* of the stream, where it cannot be read any further (basically as if you had a cassette tape movie or VHS played past the end-credits).

So make sure you reset `.Position` or use `.Seek` *after* writing to it, but before attempting to read from it:

```
using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() )
{
    using( StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter( ms, false ) )
    {
        CopyLoremIpsum( wtr );
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    
    await UploadStreamAsync( ms );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a MemoryStream object that contains the contents of a file. I would like to convert it from a MemoryStream to a FileStream in order to pass it to MS Graph's LargeFileUploadTask() method

But the docs you linked simply state that a `Stream` is required:

[image]

Yes, a `FileStream` is a `Stream` but a `MemoryStream` is also a `Stream` and is a "readable, seekable stream" like the docs say is required; it means you can just pass the `MemoryStream` you have for the `uploadStream` parameter.

Perhaps make sure you've `Seek`'d it to `Position` 0 before you pass it.. If you've just finished writing into a Memorystream, it's `Position`ed at the end. If you then pass it to something that will start reading from it, that thing usually reads nothing (because the stream is at the end) - seek the stream back to the start/where you want the upload to begin because you should assume that the thing you give it to will not seek it before reading from it

Comment: yes i realize they're both streams.  this is why i tried is as is.  The question is about the difference in how long it takes to write and exploring different options to test.

Comment: I thought the question was about getting it to upload at all; pass the memory stream, positioned from wherever you want to start the read (people often write to a memory stream then pass it off without seeking it, not realizing that you can't read from a memory stream that is positioned at the end)

Comment: yeah no worries.  But also,  I got tipped off first by @Dai so fwiw, I wanted to credit him with the answer.  thanks for the tip on using the correct terminology.

Comment: Yes indeed.. don't forget; you're allowed to upvote as well as check, and any number of answers can be upvoted if they contain some useful content